# Is it reasonable to do masonry veneer work when the temperature is 30-40°F?

Tags: masonry

Everything I find online says you shouldn't work under 40 degrees Fahrenheit.  It's currently 35 to 40°F (0-5°C) and the mason says this is okay to veneer the outside stone on.

One other mason we've been communicating with said they won't work until the spring, and the other said there is an upcharge because they have to use a tent with a heater.

Which is correct? Should I be wary of the guy that is willing to do it in these low temperatures?

Comment: Two out of three saying it is a bad idea, do not think the odds will get any better if you ask more masons.  Most stuff that needs to dry(cement, paint, glue) do not like the cold.

Comment: Well, you will be paying his heating costs...

Comment: I'm sure there's a tolerance built in the mason is taking advantage of, but why risk it if it can wait?

Comment: Not only put it off 'til spring. Put it off 'til spring and use **one of the other two masons**, in spring. Just sayin' - Also, you might want to tarp or wrap for the winter.

Comment: When I was laying brick, the rule of thumb was "35 and rising". It does depend on what the overnight temps were too. If it will drop below 32 for the first night, DO NOT lay brick.

Comment: If the mason either has materials which are specifically rated for the application temperature range, or is arranging to control the application temperature, that's one thing.  If they are ignorant of or ignoring the rated application temperature range, you are taking a risk.  Is the risk worth taking for your application in order to avoid waiting?

Comment: Well is the guy who wants to do it also going to be tenting and just didn't mention that to you? Or did he explicitly say he doesn't need to tent and heat?

Comment: If pouring concrete in cold weather they have additives and use hot water in the mix - maybe the mason is going to do something similar with the mortar?

Comment: My college dorm had anti-freeze added to the concrete mix so they could pour it in the middle of winter. 40 years later, they woke us up at 7am every. single. morning. jackhammering out the concrete so they could replace the rebar that was corroded by the antifreeze. The price of doing it wrong is high...

Answer (score 14):

You know what's more expensive than doing it right? Doing it wrong once and then doing it right.

Yes, mortar, concrete, stucco, etc all have specific cure times and temperatures for maximum strength. I believe 50-70°F (10-25°C) is optimal temperature. If it's too hot then the water will evaporate too quickly and ruin the cure.

If it is cold then the cure time is extended. The worst thing that could happen is that the material freezes before the water has had a chance to dry out and it starts crumbling.

Curing is an "exothermic" process. Yes, these products produce heat as they cure so if you need to pour a concrete fence post and the ground temperature is above freezing then it's okay to do so as long as you insulate the area exposed from the freezing air temperatures. Look up concrete blankets; sometimes concrete just needs to be poured in the middle of winter.

Realistically, your veneer should wait till the spring time since it doesn't have enough mass to maintain temperature without extensive assistance. Right now it's all risk with little reward. I doubt there is a convincing reason for you to risk this work during these temperatures.

Comment: A highly visible example of this is road construction. Some authorities try to extend the construction window out if they're running behind schedule but end up continuing when it's too cold. You end up with brand new roads being torn up in the spring due to the failures and everyone complaining.

Comment: Do you have a reference for the "specific window of time" statement? My understanding has been that as long as there's adequate moisture, time isn't really a concern. We build houses year-round in Minnesota. As long as green masonry is protected from freezing it's generally just fine.

Comment: @DWGKNZ, I'm sure it's happened, but that doesn't mean that temps above freezing are "too cold".

Comment: @isherwood I may have to remove that statement. Just the other week I had to pour some concrete footers for a roof extension so I was reading about all of the cold weather precautions and one or more sites mentioned that if weather conditions cause the cure to go beyond 4 weeks then the cure ends up about 30-40% weaker. I cannot find that article now though; 3am article readings should be used with caution I guess =)

Comment: I think the lower bound temperature is quite reasonable, as most sources recommended that, except for more strict cold region practices are followed, not to lay bricks below 2 degrees Celcius (taking windchill into account), and mortar shall be kept above 4 degrees Celcius at all time. The brickwork shall be protected for frost.

Comment: Wind chill is not a factor. Things don't get colder than the actual temperature. It just affects how quickly things cool down. Wind chill doesn't actually mean much at all except with respect to how things _feel_ to humans.

Comment: @isherwood wind chill is a factor if the temperature is lower for a short time as it results in damp bricks loosing heat much quicker.

Answer (score 2):

Sure it is. This shouldn't come down to a popularity vote as **there are certainly ways to do it correctly**. Details matter, as with most things, and yes, construction costs more in winter. The job can be done without concern through proper strategy. Masonry is done year-round in many cold climates, and it doesn't all fall apart in the spring.

- The mortar shouldn't be allowed to freeze for several days or a week. This could mean timing the weather, and it could mean building a temporary enclosure.
- The mortar can be fortified for cold weather. Calcium compounds are often used for this.
- Moisture is key, and can be used to prevent freezing. A splash of water after the mortar is adequately cured brings much thermal mass to the table. It's actually what fruit growers do in emergencies.

Bottom line: Absolutely. It all comes down to workmanship and planning.

Answer (score 0):

If temperatures are 40° you have only 8° before freezing.  If you proceed with massonry work you are at risk if temperature drops and the freezing of motar mix begins.  This in turn will create expansion the contraction which causes Spalding of both motar and rock.  After your beautiful wall or walkway is completed the masonry work should be protected by sealing it with water proofing sealer.
So now you have the question what about the rock in it's natural environment?
Think about it.

Comment: "[Spalding](https://www.spalding.com/basketball/basketball-hoops/)" the sporting good's brand, or "[spalling](https://theconstructor.org/practical-guide/spalling-concrete-causes-repair/26027/)". Please take a look at [how to write a good answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), then [edit] to provide some clarity. Your question at the end and "think about it" aren't really up to the standards we expect 'round here.